Command issue in shopware 6.4.20.2 version
As i have created a command in shopwre 6 which checks the checkbox in products and that checkbox field i have created from admin and assigned to products . and my command work properly in latest version it checks the checkbox but in shopwre 6.4.20.2 version it is runing proprely no any issue occur but it does not check the checkbox .
i was runing this commamd and expecting that it checks the checkbox.

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].
